# How to get the money value without "$" using django-money?

Tags: python, django, django-models, dollar-sign, django-money

I use [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money), then I have `price` field with `MoneyField()` in `Product` model as shown below:

```py
# "app/models.py"

from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from decimal import Decimal
from djmoney.models.validators import MaxMoneyValidator, MinMoneyValidator

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = MoneyField( # Here
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[
            MinMoneyValidator(Decimal(0.00)), MaxMoneyValidator(Decimal(999.99)),
        ]
    )
```

Then, when getting the price in `views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "app/views.py"

from app.models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    print(Product.objects.all()[0].price) # Here
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

I got the price with `$` on console as shown below:

```
$12.54
```

Now, how can I get the price without `$` as shown below?

```
12.54
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're dealing with a `Money` object ([see here](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed)). That object has an `amount` property that will give you the decimal amount:

```
>>> price.amount
Decimal('12.54')
```

Which you can then convert to `int` if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.amount` to get the price without `$`:

```py
                              # Here
Product.objects.all()[0].price.amount
```

Then, you can get the price without `$`
on console as shown below:

```
12.54
```